# Weblogic run configuration in IntelliJ idea - disable basic authentication

Tags: intellij-idea, weblogic

I need to disable basic auth on weblogic server, which can be done by adding `<enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>false</enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>` into `config.xml` in a weblogic domain.
I'm deploying a web service to weblogic directly from IntelliJ Idea and every time I start deploy, the `config.xml` is replaced by a new one, so I cannot change config manually. I guess I need to pass some extra arguments in IntelliJ's run configuration. Does anyone has any experiences with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. I tried to modify config.xml and forgot my server is still running. According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e13716/config_files.htm#DOMCF126) page I think it's pretty obvious why this happens. So, it has nothing to do with IntelliJ Idea.

> Caution: Do not edit configuration files for a domain that is
>   currently running. Because Oracle WebLogic Server rewrites the files
>   periodically, your changes will be lost. Depending on your platform,
>   you also could cause Oracle WebLogic Server failures.